# How to replace string in a file in C?

Tags: c

I need to write a program that gets input via the command line, in which the first argument is the name of the file, second the word you want to replace and third with what word you wanna replace it. If i input words with the same length the program works but when i change the length it keeps some characters. For example:

I was walking /* text in file test.txt */ Command line arguments: test.txt was am

Output: I ams walking

Main function

```
int main(int argument_count, char ** argument_vector)
```

The code:

```
FILE * stream;
char string[15];
if(stream = fopen(* (argument_vector + 1), "r+"))
{
    while(fscanf(stream, "%s", string) != EOF)
    {
        if(!(strcmp(string, * (argument_vector + 2))))
        {
            int x = -(strlen(string));
            fseek(stream, x, SEEK_CUR);
            fprintf(stream, "%s", * (argument_vector + 3));
            fseek(stream, 0, SEEK_CUR);
        }
    }
    fclose(stream);
}
else printf("Error while reading file");
return 0;
```

Comment: Instead of `*(x + n)` just do `x[n]`, it's way easier to read. By convention `main` is defined as `int main(int argc, char** argv)` so `argv[1]` is the way to do it.

Comment: the classic thing to do is to read the whole file in looking for the data you want and to write out a new file with the changes.  In place changes to text files is very hard to do

Comment: @pm100 Yeah, i cant create a new file would be much easier.

Comment: @MarkoMajstorovic Why can't you create a new file?

Comment: @tadman Was just practicing with pointer arithmetic i will keep that in mind.

Comment: if you want to overwrite the original file then write a temp file in the same dir then rename to the original

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I got that exercise as homework. I already did it with swapping characters, now i have to swap strings.

Comment: Keep in mind `x[n]` is also pointer arithmetic. In C the two are just different ways of expressing the same thing more often than not, but use the form that's the most legible. `for (char* x = y; *x; ++x)` can be it sometimes, and others it's `x[i]`.

Comment: @MarkoMajstorovic The issue (as you have already discovered) is that the file won't dynamically resize; if you match five characters and then overwrite three characters there are still two characters from the original five present in the file. Are you certain you can't write to a temp file? Can you be certain the file will fit in RAM? Please edit your question to include **all of the rules**.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch "Write a program that in a file whose name is specified as the first command line argument, replaces all occurrences of the string specified as the second command line argument with a string specified as the third command line argument."

Comment: Write new contents to a temp file, remove original file, rename temp file to the original name. The requirements you've posted don't say you can't do that, and that is the best way to do it. Note, try writing a new string value longer than the original.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Ok, thank you for the help and remove the original file using the built-in remove function ?

Comment: @MarkoMajstorovic The function you are looking for is [`unlink`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/unlink).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Hi, could you check out my code i read all the strings in the file made a new string and just wrote it down in the file again. Valgrind reports me an error and i can't find where it is. Also when i write it the first time it works but on the second one it doesn't. Thanks for any help. https://pastebin.com/6a8rHYys

Answer (score 1):

You can not change the length of your search string.

Since you want to be able to replace the original string with a string of different length, you will have to either load the file completely, modify the content, and write it back or to write to a temporary file and rename it afterwards:

```
FILE * stream;
FILE * output;

char string[15];
if(stream = fopen(* (argument_vector + 1), "r+"))
{
    output = fopen("out.txt", "w");
    while(fscanf(stream, "%s", string) != EOF)
    {
        if(!(strcmp(string, * (argument_vector + 2))))
        {
            int x = -(strlen(string));
            fprintf(output, "%s ", * (argument_vector + 3));
        }
        else {
            fprintf(output, "%s ", string);
        }
    }
    fclose(stream);
    fclose(output);


    remove(* (argument_vector + 1));
    rename("out.txt", * (argument_vector + 1));
}
else printf("Error while reading file");
return 0;
```

Note a few things:

You have to write the spaces between the words yourself now. They were left in the file buffer for the same reason as the undesired character. Therefore the space in the fprintf calls.

This is a very basic implementation. You can **only** replace words in written text. If you want to replace parts of words or multiple words you will have to use `strstr` to find the substrings.

**One last very, very important note**: using `fscanf(stream, "%s", string)` is a massive security flaw. You can write anything to the buffer **and beyond**. This is called a buffer overflow. Not relevant now, but some day you might want to write code where it matters.